Colorbar with custom LogNorm does not work properly
I modified LogNorm from matplotlib.colors such that the midpoint on the logscale can be set manually. The 2D colorplot changes accordingly with the new normalised colormap, but the colorbar stays the same with the old unmodified colormap.
There is already a similar code:
Shifted logarithmic colorbar, white color offset to center
With the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,0,19), np.arange(10))
f = lambda x,y : 10**x*(1+y)
z = f(x,y)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12,4.8))

im = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", norm=LogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max()))
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("LogNorm")

class MidPointLogNorm(LogNorm):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        LogNorm.__init__(self,vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=clip)
        self.midpoint=midpoint
    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [np.log(self.vmin), np.log(self.midpoint), np.log(self.vmax)], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(np.log(value), x, y))


im2 = ax2.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", 
                            norm=MidPointLogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), midpoint=1))
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("MidPointLogNorm")
plt.show()


The code no longer works properly. You can see that the 2D colorplots have different colormaps, but the colorbars are the same.
How to fix this issue? Is there an issue with matplotlib?

It seems like the other answer in your linked question works just fine to center the color scale by setting vcenter in norm=TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=2)

@TrentonMcKinney  Maybe the question is also related to this closed github issue? In that case, additionally cbar.ax.set_yscale('linear') would be needed in that other answer (to be called before cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(...)). It's a rather confusing change in matplotlib. I've no idea how the class MidPointLogNorm(LogNorm) could be adapted.

@TrentonMcKinney It puts vcenter to the center of the colorbar by compressing the scale from one side and extending at the other side, which doesn't look great. I needed the numbers on the scale to stay at their positions and to normalise the colourmap instead.


You forgot to define the inverse method in your normalization class. The inverse method is called from Colorbar to map the normalized values to data and in your example Colorbar had to use the inverse method of the base class, that is not aware of your mid point...
Please see the code below for the definition of inverse.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

class MidPointLogNorm(LogNorm):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        LogNorm.__init__(self,vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=clip)
        self.midpoint=midpoint
    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [np.log(self.vmin), np.log(self.midpoint), np.log(self.vmax)], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(np.log(value), x, y))
    def inverse(self, value):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a simple example
        vmin, mid, vmax = self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax
        a1, a2 = 2*np.log(mid/vmin), 2*np.log(vmax/mid)
        k1, k2 = vmin, mid*mid/vmax
        return np.where(value<0.5, k1*np.exp(a1*value), k2*np.exp(a2*value))

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,0,19), np.arange(10))
z = 10**x*(1+y)

norm = MidPointLogNorm(vmin=0.001, vmax=10, midpoint=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z, cmap="RdBu_r", norm=norm)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

plt.show()

